# how to keep horizontal scroll for prime Ng table body ,as horizontal scroll bar is not visible only right and left arrows are showing as below

Tags: angular, primeng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wPzw.png)how to keep horizontal scroll for prime Ng table body ,as horizontal scroll bar is not visible only right and left arrows are showing as below

[image]

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-table-resizable>.ui-table-wrapper {
        overflow-x: scroll !important;
     
        // width: 1200px;
       
        // height:4px !important;
        display: block !important;
        // width:50%;
    
      
    }
```

Comment: It seems that the `.ui-table-wrapper` element already takes up the entire width it needs so  placing the `overflow-x: scroll !important` style on it doesn't do anything except adding a scrollbar. You need to find the ancestor of the element that doesn't overflow off-screen and then either add a scrollbar there or set its overflow-x to hidden and limit the width of its child to 100% and do for each child until you get to the `.ui-table-wrapper` element.

Comment: please ,can you elaborate your answer with .I didnt get you

Comment: i added horizontal scroll for complete div i got horizontal scroll but i dont want like that. I need horizontal scroll only for body of table

Comment: What version of primeNG are you using?

Comment: primeng version8

Comment: am doing it on static p-table not dynamic table.